# Does Tiles for Struts2 support UTF-8 encoded templates?

Tags: java, internationalization, tiles

If so what are required configuration elements to enable UTF-8 for tiles?

I'm finding my tile results are sent as:

```
Content-Type    text/html;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you put this at the top?

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" language="java" %>
```

Comment: Yeah I have :/

Viewing the same page as a jsp result (rather than a tile result) responds in a UTF-8 encoded page.